# Convert OLECHAR* to CString in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cstring

How to convert `OLECHAR*` to `CString` in VC++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OLECHAR*` is the same as `BSTR`.  You can convert to `CString` like this (sorry about formatting, I have lost the `code` icon for now).

`OLECHAR* value;`

`BSTR (bstrValue(value));`

`_bstr_t tmp(bstr, FALSE);   //wrap the BSTR`

`CString cs(static_cast<const char*>(tmp));  //convert it`

Comment: A `BSTR` is NULL-terminated and points to the beginning of the string. So could you just do `CString cs(value);`?

Comment: Is OLECHAR* the same as BSTR? 
I was under the impression that OLECHAR* is the same as WCHAR * which is the same as wchar_t. BSTR's are more restrictive than an array of wchar_t